# Referencing Images in Stencil Themes

Tags: bigcommerce

For BigCommerce stencil themes having references to assets, the docs do not mention CSS and SASS URL references.

Is there a specialized SASS function for referencing images in the asserts directory, in BigCommerce stencil themes? Or, will CDN reference strings be converted automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing images that are bundled with your theme, you can use a path like `../images/myimage.png` and it will load from the CDN. If you are referencing images from outside of the theme, there is no SASS function and you will need to hardcode the CDN URL (or use inline css to utilize the CDN handlebars helper).

Comment: I am referencing them as "/assets/img/*". Is there a difference between that and the relative path call?

Answer (score 0):

Alyss's answer helped, in your CSS you can reference theme assets with the path he provided:

```
../images/myimage.png
```

For inline, you can refence them by using the CDN handlebars syntax:

```
<link href="{{cdn '/assets/css/invoice.css'}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

More info here:
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/css-resources